# What is the rarest thing you can fish in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Please look at this from a mathematical perspective. If you did, include math and sources. I will be using some data from here for a project.

Comment: Most questions offer a premise on this site. Is there a reason you want to know what the rarest item is? Otherwise, this seems like a low effort question

Comment: I want to know to see if it's qualified for a YouTube video on Minecraft probabilities.

Comment: Just two words "minecraft fishing" takes you to the [Official Minecraft Wiki - Fishing](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Fishing) page which has all the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [0.9% chance of catching 10 ink sacs in a jungle biome](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing), the rarest catch in the game. The second rarest is 1% for 10 ink sacs in a normal fishing environment. There's not really "math" to get that number besides understanding weights, which is just a natural number telling how common  drop should be.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118222/discussion-on-answer-by-penguin-what-is-the-rarest-thing-you-can-fish-in-minecra).